# How to allow quotation mark in jquery input mask

Tags: jquery-inputmask

How to allow the double quote in query input mask validator

> ```
>           remarks:{                   
>               alias: "Regex",
>               regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9-.@()&-,?"//]*$",
>               repeat:14
>           },
> ```

If i add the " (quotation mark) in the reges or validator, it does not allow and throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

use \ to escape a special character .. just try it

```
regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9-.@()&-,?\"]*$"
```

Comment: Sorry i tried already, it is saying syntax error illegal token